# How do I reduce the white space / blank rows in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using VS 2010 and CR13. I have multiple data sources.

I have a rows of different student loans that repeat. Between each row there is a good amount of white space which is driving me crazy. Any options I can tick to make this go away? I have Keep Together and Suppress Blank checked, so I'm missing something.

Comment: Post a picture of your report in design and preview mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any white space at the end of your row, it will show up on the report.

To remove white space, make sure your report fields are of an appropriate height, and drag the horizontal bar at the bottom of the detail section up so that it is touching the bottom of your report fields.

For example:

This is bad, and will cause white space:

```
-Detail section-------------------------------------------------------
+--------------+ +--------------+
| Report field | | Report field |
+--------------+ +--------------+


----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is good:

```
-Detail section-------------------------------------------------------
+--------------+ +--------------+
| Report field | | Report field |
+--------------+ +--------------+
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Pro tip: right click the section's left gutter and choose 'Fit section'.

Comment: @craig - **wow**, I've somehow never seen that option there before.

Comment: That did it. Btw, is there a way I can alternate rows with the classic blue and white highlights?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126556/alternating-the-background-color-of-rows-or-text-boxes

Comment: @user1290284 - sure; right-click the Detail section, select `Format Section...`, go to the Color tab, click the Formula Editor, and enter `IF RecordNumber MOD 2 = 1 THEN AQUA ELSE WHITE`.